# Difference Seed and Faker library

Tags: laravel

In order to create dummy data in Laravel application, which is the best choice between seeding database or using Faker library? I have ever look up both of these method but not in depth learning.

Answer (score 1):

Seeding and faker are not same.Seeding is a system of inserting dummy data in table.And faker used for generate dummy data.So you can write dummy data without using faker.

See in laravel project there is a example of using faker in `project/database/factories/ModelFactory.php`

In here faker is only work for data generate not seeding.

If you want to seeding with faker,first create a seeding(https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/seeding#writing-seeders) then use that model factory in `run` method,like this

```
public function run()
{
    factory(\App\User::class,10)->create();
}
```

Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you don't want to involve the database at all as it is very slow comparably and will make tests take a long time to complete, especially when you start to have a mature application on your hands with hundreds.

You will want to look at mocking (https://laracasts.com/lessons/mock-that-thang) and I would suggest have a look at the myriad other videos out there (on laracasts and beyond) on how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

With seeding you can easily create specific data in your database. For example when I reset my database and run my migrations again, I use seeding to create an admin account so I can login to my application.

This seed contains specific information like the email address and a password so I can login.

To test my application I would use the Faker library cause it will just generate random data that I can use for testing. For example: I can create multiple users in my application. I can then edit those users or delete them. But I would not be able to login with those users cause I don't know the password Fake created for them.

Hope this helps a bit in deciding what to use.